# Vue 3 (CLI): Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'get')

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-cli

When switching to Vue 3 CLI and consequently refactoring the code, `this.$http.get('/api/todo/')` no longer works. Instead of being returned a list of todos from the database, I receive a `Cannot read properties of undefined` error in the console:

```
app.js:209 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'get')
    at Proxy.getTodos (Todos.vue?4897:38:1)
    at Proxy.mounted (Todos.vue?4897:28:1)
    at eval (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?d2dd:2722:1)
    at callWithErrorHandling (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?d2dd:155:1)
    at callWithAsyncErrorHandling (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?d2dd:164:1)
    at hook.__weh.hook.__weh (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?d2dd:2697:1)
    at flushPostFlushCbs (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?d2dd:341:1)
    at render (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?d2dd:6247:1)
    at mount (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?d2dd:4440:1)
    at app.mount (runtime-dom.esm-bundler.js?2725:1574:1)
```

Additionally, I observe that both the apps and components lists are empty in Vue devtools.

After searching and experimenting with solutions for a few hours, I have not found a solution that works yet.

This is the current code causing the issues:

In **Todos.vue**, the template is rendered because I do se "Hi there", but I do not see any list items anymore:

```
<template>
    <div id="TODOS">
      Hi there
      <ol>
        <li v-for="todo in v_todos" :key="todo.id">
          <span style="color:red;">{{ todo.name }}</span>
        </li>
      </ol>
    </div>
  </template>
  
  <script>
  export default {
    // el: "#TODOS",
    name: 'Todos',
    
    data() {
      return {
        v_todos: [],
      }
    },
  
    computed: {},
    components: {},
  
    mounted() {
        this.getTodos();
    },
  
    methods: {
          getTodos: function () {
              this.$http.get('/api/todo/')
                  .then((response) => { 
                    this.v_todos = response.data; 
                })
                  .catch((err) => { 
                    console.log(err); 
                })
          },
  }
  </script>
```

In **App.vue**:

```
<template>
    <div id="App">
      <Todos />
    </div>
    
  </template>
  
  <script>
  import Todos from './components/Todos.vue'
  
  export default {
    name: 'App',
    components: {
      Todos
    }
  }
  </script>
```

In the HTML page **todos.html**:

```html
...
<div id="App"></div>
...
```

In **base.html**, at the end of the body:

```html
  <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'src/vue/dist/js/chunk-vendors.js' %}"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'src/vue/dist/js/app.js' %}"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue-resource@1.3.5"></script>
```

I am completely new to Vue, so I would strongly appreciate if solution proposals are presented in a simple-to-understand way.

Comment: how to put `$http` object to `this` ? check your `this.$http`

Comment: @SefaUn Can you please clarify what you mean by that? `this.$http` is used in `Todos.vue`.

Comment: where did you implement `$http` in your project ?

Comment: In Todos.vue -> script -> export default -> methods -> getTodos function. Please see the 10th last  line in the first code block.

Comment: anyway, could you try this. add this code to your `main.js`.
`import axios from 'axios'
const app = createApp(App);
app.config.globalProperties.$http = axios;`

Comment: @Christian What is leading you to believe that `this.$http` is a thing?  The docs make no mention of it.  If you are migrating from Vue 1.x, that object was deprecated and removed awhile ago.  I'm trying to find the notice right now.

Comment: @SefaUn this worked as long as I added `app.mount('#App');` after your suggested code. Please convert your comment to an answer and I'll accept this. Thank you!

Comment: @Daedalus I started learning Vue just yesterday but reading tutorials on Vue+Django and seeing actual code. It's just from there that I've learned about `this.$http`. Since it's deprecated, can you please clarify what is considered proper use for Vue 3?

Comment: @Christian Seems I mis-remembered a slight; turns out it was never apart of vue directly, but was linked to vue as a recommended library: https://medium.com/the-vue-point/retiring-vue-resource-871a82880af4

Comment: @Daedalus thank you for clarifying and sharing the resource!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add to your `main.js`

```
import axios from 'axios';

const app = createApp(App);

app.config.globalProperties.$http = axios;
```

Comment: This worked as long as I added `app.mount('#App');` after your suggested code.